# Not working !==NULL

Tags: php, isnull

In my app I have a table in where I'd like lo highlight some rows if a date field is empty, here's my code:

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($conts as $cont): ?>
<tr <?php if ($cont['Cont']['shdate']!==NULL) echo 'class="bg-success"'; ?>>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

It does not work although I've checked in the database and the field is NULL, why could this be happening?

Comment: what does `$cont['Cont']['shdate']` contain?

Comment: `var_dump` or debug your code, it will then be easy to notice. It definitely has to be something different to `NULL`.

Comment: Probably your array does not look like you think it does. Post it or we won't be able to help

Comment: It's probably a `NULL` string. `var_dump` it and see what it actually is. https://3v4l.org/rlDv1

Comment: Damn, that was it, a NULL string...jesus. var_dump showed it. Thank you very much guys.

Comment: If you don't need the NULLs you could just filter it in the query. `and shdate is not NULL`. (that assumes it is really NULL in the db, if `null` string use `!= 'null'` or if empty `<> ''`.